# XCode 4.31 crash when open my project

Tags: ios, xcode

XCode 4.31 crash when i try to open my project. I could open any other project except mine.

I recall I was changing some values in .plist file when the problem happened. however, I fix .plist (by text editor) but still Xcode crash.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new project and import your files in it. Configure it accordingly.

Comment: how do I import story.board file which i build through interface builder

Comment: Just import it like any other file.

Comment: how in hell is this a solution? i have a huge project with hundrets of files and git dependency... "simply drag and drop" is not really a sultion...

Comment: It was sufficient for the problem that occured at that time, evidently.